# PPPoE connection problem

Tags: ubuntu, internet, services, backtrack

I have just installed Backtrack 5 R2 and I'm finding it difficult to make a DSL internet connection. What troubles me is that I think I have all the steps figured out, and after completing them, the browser still won't load the page. The steps are:

1. run `pppoeconf`
2. after the window pops out i follow the steps, enter my username & password and after finishing (basically just approving everything it says by clicking on yes) it automatically starts `pon dsl-provider`
3. Finally I start the networking service.

The browser doesn't load the requested page. I don't know if I'm doing anything wrong here. I have tried to start the networking service before step 1 but it still doesn't load.

However, after starting it, the konsole outputs `networking stop/waiting` (both times). It might be an issue. Also I instantiate my network interface which is eth0 but still doesn't work. It is a wired connection btw.

Comment: Having stareted PPPoE issue `ip ad` command, show us its output.